# For loop in batches

Tags: objective-c, loops, for-loop

Whats the best way to do batches in a for loop? All apis today have a max number of items that can be fetched. 
Eg, batch of 100 tweets. In this case if I have a list of 1001 ids that I want to query information about then I need to make 11 calls with a batch of 100 each. I would use a for loop with conditions in the body to call the task once a batch of 100 is formed. 
Is there a better way to do this?
Shouldn't there be a built in construct in languages to handle this, given that it is a common pattern? Am I missing something?

Comment: A `for` loop can do that, yes.  What's the problem?

Comment: Why do you think Objective-C (or other languages) should have a special construct in the language just because some 3rd party web APIs have a limit to the number of requests that can be made at a time?

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C you could build your own extra construct if you want one:

```
@interface NSArray (OKBatchedSubarrays)

// this will return an array of subarrays, with each of those
// containing no more items than batchSize, and the order of input
// objects being preserved
- (NSArray *)subarraysWithBatchSize:(NSUInteger)batchSize;

@end

...

@implementation NSArray (OKBatchedSubarrays)

- (NSArray *)subarraysWithBatchSize:(NSUInteger)batchSize
{
     NSMutableArray *outputBatches = [NSMutableArray array];

     // or arrayWithCapacity:([self count] + (batchSize - 1)) / batchSize
     // if you want to be really explicit, but it's not important to the example

     NSRange subarrayRange = NSMakeRange(0, batchSize);
     while(subarrayRange.location < self.count)
     {
         // make sure we're not about to ask for out-of-bounds data
         if(subarrayRange.location + subarrayRange.length > self.count)
             subarrayRange.length = self.count - subarrayRange.location;

         // add another batch to the output array
         [outputBatches addObject:[self subarrayWithRange:subarrayRange]];

         // advance beyond the range we just grabbed
         subarrayRange.location += subarrayRange.length;
     }

     return outputBatches;
}

@end
```

Then elsewhere you'd just do:

```
NSArray *thingsToFetch = <... whatever ...>;

for(NSArray *batch in [thingsToFetch subarraysWithBatchSize:100])
{
    // post to server with all things in 'batch'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd combine a while and for loop

```
    int totalItems = 1001;
    int batchSize = 100;
    int i = 0;

    while ( i < totalItems ){
         [self fetchABatch:(totalItems-i)];
         i += batchSize;
    }


    -(void)fetchABatch:(int) count
    {
           if ( count > batchSize ){
                 // fetch full batch
           }else{
                batchSize = count;
                // fetch a partial batch
          }
    }
```

Comment: Where's the `for` loop?

Comment: Sorry, I started with a for loop inside the while and decided it was better to stuff that in a different method. If you're pulling data from the net it's likely to have a lot of code. This will make it more readable.

Comment: Yes but it seems like a common pattern nowadays that just needs something like forbatch where you specify the batch size as one of the parameters instead of doing a mod etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the API restricts you to 100 records at a time, then yes you will need to make 11 requests, there is no getting around that.

I'd probably create an `NSOperation` that encapsulates the request for each page, create one for all the pages you need (11 in this case) then drop them into an `NSOperationQueue`, as each operation finishes you can take their results and drop them into one consolidated array in memory or maybe write them to Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But if you want to do something in a for loop every 100 times just do
if(i%100==0){
//do my thing
       }